# jumping controllers in code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, routes

I am wanting to have a form of dynamic routing.

Basically I want to catch the 404 (done through routes.php 404_override).

This is easy enough.

But then what I want to do is run through a series of checks.

e.g *pay no attention to the fact the `is_xxx` functions are not coming from anywhere*

```
$what = $this->uri->segment(1);
if(is_vanity_name($what)){
    //now I want to route this to the profile controller and call the display function like so 
    //display('vanity', $what);
}
elseif(is_region_name($what)){
    if(($deal = $this->uri->segment(2)) !== false){
        //now I want to route to the deals controller can call the display function like so
        //display($deal, $what);
    } 
    else {
        //now I want to route to the deals controller and call the daily function like so
        //daily($what);
    }
}
elseif(is_deal_name($what)){
    //now I want to route to the deals controller and call the display function like so
    //display($what);
}
else{
    $this->load->view('errors/404');
}
```

And thats a pretty basic example!

So my question is,
How would I go about re-routing to the other controllers once the decision has been made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Broadly speaking, its kind of messy doing this with CodeIgniter. Coming from java land the RequestDispatcher.forward() takes care of these sorts of things, but in PHP space its usually a redirect(): there typically isn't the server side infrastructure to (effectively) pass requests from one PHP file to another without the client-side round trip.

Looking through Google's eyes: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/55212/P15/ is a long discussion with a CI helper that *claims* to let you do this, http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Wick/ is a library that appears to actually do it.

Let me know if either of those work out: you might be better off refactoring those out, but that does get tedious after awhile so I can understand the desire to just pass the handling off to the other controller (why bother round-tripping if you don't have to).

Comment: cheers, Very useful, Seriously though, I am sure that proper dynamic routing is one of the most requested features....

Comment: Would be nice: not sure there are any PHP frameworks that manage that natively.